# How i define a 1 to N relation in storage?

Tags: pallet, frame, storage

i'm trying to define a 1 to `N storage relation` in my pallet. I have a `Resource` (owned by an account ) which will be linked to N `Use` structs ( kind of a set )

```
- Account #1
  --> Resource #A
         ---> Use #1
         ---> Use #2
         ---> Use #N

- Account #2
  --> Resource #B
         ---> Use #3
         ---> Use #4
         ---> Use #N'
```

From the architectural perspective, what's the best way to define these kind of relationships in the storage?

Of course the goal of this is to be able to query the three.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example is worth 1000 words: Have a look at the uniques pallet in substrate that stores two levels. Uniques are NFTs. One can mint a unique class and then under a particular class, one can mint individual instances of that class. (There's also metadata associated with the class level and the instance level that can be retrieved)

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/7a09b82772b0597cdae224f4b124d660dda9e82b/frame/uniques/src/lib.rs#L195

(If you want more levels than a double map, you can use an N Storage map which you can read up about here: https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/storage/ )

Comment: thanks for your answer! quick question:

Once i have the storages defined, is there any way to query the storage tree like this:

`select * from resources where account = '12';`

Comment: I'm less familiar with the JS side of things but I believe this reads all the keys for a particular account: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/3df2aaa1ca25d00d525b16a3a432412c5b5b597b/packages/page-nfts/src/AccountItems/useAccountItems.ts#L39